# Prove the root test for sequence convergence with $\limsup$.

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

I am trying to prove the root test for sequence convergence with $\limsup$.

I know exactly what to do but I think I misunderstood a simple detail when I learned about $\limsup$ and $\liminf$. That if $(a_n)$ is a sequence then we can find $N$ that for all $n>N$ the sequence is bounded with the $\limsup+\epsilon$.

If I knew how to prove it (in case it was true), that would help with my solution.

A hint would really make a difference.

I tried to search a  lot but unfortunately I couldn't find something that answers my question.

Thank you!

Comment: If $\limsup a_n = A$, then for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that for all $n>N$ you have $
a_n < A+\epsilon
$.
Is this the detail you miunderstood?

Comment: Yes. To be more specific, I don't know how to prove it (if it was true).

Answer (score 1):

**Claim:** If $$
\limsup a_n = A 
$$
and $\epsilon>0$, then there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>N$, $$
a_n < A+\epsilon
$$
**Proof:** I'm assuming your definition of $\limsup$ is the [first one from Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#Definition_for_sequences) If your class uses the other one, you can modify this proof accordingly.
$$
\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sup_{m\ge n} a_n\right) 
$$
If this converges to $A$, by definition of a limit, there exists $N$ such that for $n>N$, $$
\left|\sup_{m\ge n} a_n - A\right| <\epsilon
$$
and hence \begin{eqnarray}
\sup_{m\ge n} a_n - A &<& \epsilon\\
\sup_{m\ge n} a_n &<&A +\epsilon
\end{eqnarray}
hence $a_n < A+\epsilon$ for all $n>N$.